# How to determine USB device class and store device number?

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, usb

I am making a script to determine if a connected USB device is a mass storage device, and if so, store the device number. I'd also like for it to work with multiple connected USB sticks.

Here is the basic idea:

If `lsusb -t | grep Class=Mass` matches, then save the device ID as a variable.

```
   |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
               ^^^^^
```

In other words: How do I take "Dev x", if the words after it matches my search?

I am not that experienced with Linux, bash or regex. If this is weird or impractical, then I am open for other suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use awk:

```
lsusb -t | awk -F '[:,]''/Class=Mass/{print $2}'
```

We search for `Class=Mass`, the delimiter is `:` and `,` if we find `Class=Mass` then we print column two of the output, which will leave you with:

```
Dev 5
```